# Unable to open Admin interface (Server not found) and Query console?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I was going through the developer tutorials of MarkLogic and tried to create a Rest API instance through curl commad -

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -d@"Desktop/mls-fundamentals/unit04/config.json" -i -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis
```

The command didn't executed till the end but kept executing or perhaps it got stuck somewhere. I closed the terminal and tried to open admin interface where I am getting `server not found` error and query console page is showing this -

```
503 Service Unavailable

XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Modules not mounted: disconnected
```

Is there a soultion to this problem? I haven't created any backup. Do i need to re intall MarkLogic server?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I downloaded centOs ova file to my window 7..I actually downloaded again and followed the procedure.. It worked this time

Comment: For Windows, it's important to run "Start MarkLogic" as an administrator. Perhaps that was missed the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe you're taking the Fundamentals Self-Paced course you could do the following:

Verify what the curl statement that you've executed created. Login to the Admin Interface (http://localhost:8001) and check if there's an App Server, Database and Forest that match the config found in 'Desktop/mls-fundamentals/unit04/config.json'.

You could manually delete those - so delete the App Server, the Forest, and then the Database and try to run that curl statement again. Don't close the terminal window until you see a response from curl.

Comment: 8000 port is also not opening

Comment: You can try to reinstall MarkLogic - something has probably gone wrong at this point which would be very had to pinpoint using this forum

Comment: I tried doing but didn't worked..I have again downloaded ova file